# no Resource Identifier found for attribute (94 errors! O_O)

Tags: android, xml, manifest

After removing the project:node from my code, I get 94 errors that all have "no resource identifier found for attirbute____". What is causing this? One of my manifests had a Project Node for the SDK which can not be used and this happened after removing it. All of my gradle files are targeting and compiling with the latest SDK and build tools. I would post the code but it is way too much to post. I have tried invalidating/restarting, cleaning, and checking the SDK and build. None worked. I am running the latest version of Android Studio and I am using the latest Build tools and Gradle Version 1.0.0. Any help would be appreciated :)

(//I might not respond or fix any code until I get from school. It is late at night for me)

Comment: I can post some code too but I can't post all of it. Too many files and errors.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of attributes missing?

Comment: Do you mean the attribute being shown in the error? (I can give you this around 5 pm Central Time. That's when I get back from school)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar issues with gradle, but they're usually fixed by clean/build.

You could try creating a new project, deleting the new project's \app\src\main folder, then dropping your project's main folder in its place.

Comment: I will try that in the morning and tell you the results. Thanks. But I have several main folders. Each with different gradles and libraries. Is that safe considering that?

Comment: I might have to try this after school.

Comment: I tried that and got the same error. It seems like my code actually needs tools:node. When it is in there, all the errors are gone except for the error for having tools:node. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Apologies; manifest merging is beyond my experience. I did find [this resource on tools:node](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-tools:node-markers), which may be helpful.

Comment: That's ok. At least you tried to help me :) I might just have to do a complete overhaul for my app. That may be the only option.